# Substitution of variable to array position

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, generate-series

I have a function which returns string similar to regexp_split_to_array function:

```
SELECT 'some_string', a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6] 
 FROM regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f', ',') d(a);
```

Instead of numbers indicating position in array I would like to use generate_series function, but when i'm doing cross join records are multiplicated:

```
SELECT 'some_string', a[n], a[n], a[n], a[n], a[n], a[n] 
 FROM regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f', ',') d(a),
      generate_series(1,6) n;
```

Is there a way to get only one line with substitution of array position from generate_series?